# Swagger-php: How to enable verbose to check excluded directories?

Tags: php, openapi, swagger-php

Using [Swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) and the following command, how can I make it show the folders/files it searches so that I can check my excudes actually work?

```php
$openapi = \OpenApi\scan('./myfolder', [
    'exclude' => ['/vendor/', '/node_modules/', '/migrations/'],
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no code in swagger-php to log each filename being processed. It's a good idea though... https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/issues/1410

As a one-off you could just manually add logging around line 492 in `\OpenApi\Generator.php`

Comment: Yes, I found out I could dump `$source` in `scanSources()` in that file. Works for now.

Comment: Debug logging of filenames was added in swagger-php v4.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Run with the `--debug` parameter and it will log the files it is processing.